# Incrementing id attribute value through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to dynamically add rows to a table to take orders and have created a `javascript` function for it.

```
function addnewrow()
    {
        var lastid = $("#table tr:last").attr("id");
        var newid=lastid+1;
        var newcolumn = document.createElement("tr");
        newcolumn.id=newid;
        newcolumn.innerHTML = "<td id='no"+newid+"'><a class='cut'>-</a>"+newid+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+
                "<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID='prod"+newid+"' runat='server' DataSourceID='SqlDataSource2' DataTextField='pname' DataValueField='pid' MaxLength='0' style='display: inline;'></ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>" +
            "</td>"+
            "<td><input type='number' required='required' min='1' name='quantity" + newid + "' /></td>" +
            "<td id='price" + newid + "'></td>" +
            "<td id='amount" + newid + "'></td>";
        document.getElementById("table").appendChild(newcolumn);
    }
```

I am doing this to get the values of all the elements in the code behind file to put them in database.
but due to this i get an error in the aspx.designer.cs page saying semicolon expected

```
protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox prod" + newid + ";
```

ASP.NET Code

```
<table class="Grid" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Enter Order Details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr No.</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="1">
            <td><a class="cut">-</a>1</td>
            <td>
                <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="prod1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="pname" DataValueField="pid" MaxLength="0" style="display: inline;"></ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:micoConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [pid], [pname] FROM [Products]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
            <td><input type="number" required="required" min="1" name="quantity1" /></td>
            <td id="price1"></td>
            <td id="amount1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<a class="add" onclick="addnewrow()" href="#">+</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$("#btnAddSchedule").click(function () {
    var trs = $("[id^=trSchedules]");
    var numberofrows = trs.length;
    var newtr = $('#' + trs[0].id).clone();
    $(newtr).attr('id', $(newtr).attr('id').replace(/\d+/, numberofrows));
    newtr.find("input,select,img").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+/, numberofrows));
        $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/, numberofrows));
        if ($(this).attr('type') != "hidden") {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        else if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf('DataExportQueueID') == -1) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        if ($(this).attr("type") == "checkbox") {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            $(this).parent().html($(this).parent().html().replace(/\d+/g, numberofrows));
        }
        if ($(this).attr("type") == "button") {
            $(this).attr("onclick", "deleteSchedule(this,0);");
        }
    });
    $('#' + trs[numberofrows - 1].id).after(newtr);
    CrossCheckScheduleRows();
});
function CrossCheckScheduleRows() {

    $('[id^=trSchedules]').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var index = row[0].rowIndex - 2;
        row.attr('id', row.attr('id').replace(/\d+/, index));
        row.find("input,select,img").each(function () {
            $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+/, index)).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/, index));

        });
    });

}
```

I use this for the same purpose, maybe it will help you

Comment: That's using jQuery library.

Comment: so you copied your first row as it is and just replaced the id attribute's number with the new number ? ill try this now thanks

Comment: Id is replaced with row count